# How to ReGenerate String Array using Some Keyword

Tags: android, string, arrays

My Question is that I have An String array of 5 Contains Value as follow :

red, green, yellow, white, black

Now I am searching some text using EditText, If User Enters : "re" then my array should be like this :

```
Search String 1 : re
output array should be: Red, Green


Search String 2 : w
Output Array should be: yellow, white
```

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have a look at this piece of documentation.. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete

Comment: Thanks for your comments but that doesn't suite my question. my question is that i want to keep only few elements from String Array and want to remove all other elements that's string doesn't contain my test.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? If you try using a hard-coded search string, can you filter the values in the list?

Comment: You need not worry about maintaining the String array. AutoCompleteTextView and ArrayAdapter manage it for you. Follow the link I have shared above.

Comment: Actually I have added few categories in to String Array and later i bound this with ListBox to display list of categories. Now I would like to apply filter based on some keywords for this I will provide EditText on the top of the Activity and Want to filter my string array as per the text entered in EditText and want to regenerate my ListView as per my new String Array. (Here I need to add few elementes from String array after finding some text.)

Comment: Hello Everyone.. If you have any solutions, please let me know.. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the AutoCompleteTextView to provide results with one character input, add this line;

```
textView.setThreshold(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Sameer for your reply, Actually I have added few categories in to String Array and later i bound this with ListBox to display list of categories. Now I would like to apply filter based on some keywords for this I will provide EditText on the top of the Activity and Want to filter my string array as per the text entered in EditText and want to regenerate my ListView as per my new String Array. (Here I need to add few elementes from String array after finding some text.)